# Prison Architect- Dog Patrols don't work

Tags: prison-architect

I have 40 dogs and around 10 - 15 patrol routes with dogs assigned to them, but only on about half the routes dogs are present. Most of the Dogs are bugging around their crates, but 10 of them still are walking free in some of the walkways.

How can I force them to go to the patrol routes?

Side-question: Does anyone know why they bugging around the doors?

EDIT:

[image]

This is the layout so you can see where the patrols should be - all around the cube in between the fences - 2 in a straight line side by side for each side (north, west, east). You can also see the Kennel Area.

[image]

And this is where the Dogs are most of the time, at totally random places, all over the Prison or at the Kennel (not resting but hanging around).

Comment: Could you show us a screenshot of your prison? This would really help us find the problem.

Comment: ATM not, i am "working hard" at work... But its nothing special - a big entrance and than blockwise cells. On the Top of the cellblocks is a big Fence in which the Dogs have thier boxes.

Comment: Whenever you can will be fine.

Comment: Could you screenshot the deployment screen?

Comment: i will when i be back at the game.

Comment: Is this still relevant? I.e. can you reproduce this issue in the current version of the game?

Comment: @ Sergii Zaskaleta I did not play the game since febuary. so i dont know....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there have been several bug fixes to resolve exactly this issue, and there are no valid answers to the question. (Relating to badp's answer [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5727/what-should-be-done-with-out-of-version-questions/5728)